# Keep scrollbars in browser when fancybox is open

Tags: jquery, fancybox

Is there any way to keep the scrollbars active in the browser when the fancybox is open? When I click on a link that opens a fancybox window, the whole page jumps to the right because the scrollbar is made inactive when the box opens.

Thanks a lot in advance :-)

Answer (score 0):

Found this for fancybox version 2.1.3:

```
$(".fancybox").fancybox({
        helpers : {
            overlay : {
                locked : false
            }
        }       
    });
```

Which solved the problem :-)

Comment: And best as I thought I've figured it out it turns out that the fancybox is no longer positioning itself to the center of a resized window :-/ Anyone knows of a fix to this?

Comment: it does, check you have `autoCenter : true`